# What does it mean by "no need to make a song and dance"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Drama movie "*The Remains of the Day*",

Scene Description:

> Lord Darlington request Mr Steven (Butler) for Steven Sr(who also a
>   butler) take a leave on important meeting, because Steven Sr is too
>   old to serve as Butler at important meeting.

Sentences:

> Lord Darlington: I'm so busy with this conference. Of course, you are too but someone has to tell him. In a way, it would be easier for
>   you. Less awkward.
>   I'd find the task rather daunting, I'm afraid.........
>
> Stevens: I shall do my best.
>
> Lord Darlington: I'd be grateful if you'd try. It'd be a lot off my mind.
>    There's **no need to make a song and dance of it**. Just convey the facts.

Comment: [To *make a song and dance about something* is an idiom meaning "to make a big deal about something, to make something seem more important than it really is."](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/make-a-song-and-dance-about-sth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20a%20song%20and%20dance%20about%20(something))

> **make a song and dance about (something)**
>
> 1. to cause a lot of excitement about (something)
> 2. to complain about (something) in a way that is excessive or unnecessary

In a way, you could consider "making a song and dance" to be equivalent to "being dramatic". I don't know if the phrase is derived specifically from musical theater, but it's always evoked the image in my head, particularly with the big song numbers.

In the case of this scene, Lord Darlington is telling Stevens not to be dramatic about telling Stevens Sr. Just "convey", or give him, the facts, as Darlington says.